# stripe checkout send extra parameters

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

Please check the code bellow. I am trying to add a checkout payment from stripe. Code bellow works already. But i want to transfer one meta data from checkout html which is `data-id="123"` then i want to grab this id from controller `metaData.Add("DomainID", "set id here")` but i am not getting any documentation how can i send this value from html to mvc5 `Charge` controller. Any idea? i am following [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder) from stripe

Html:

```
<a class="btn checkout-button" data-id="123">Check Out</a>
```

JS:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51H5JwbI0Y3sF_fake_2keibuWoD8nKTm6joRYPXRH7Nk7t6dqo1OetP3rPQRR005SfevmAY");

    var checkoutButton = document.getElementsByClassName("checkout-button")[0];
    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        fetch("/Settings/Charge", {
            method: "POST",
        }).then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function (session) {
                return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
            }).then(function (result) {
                // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
                // error, you should display the localized error message to your
                // customer using error.message.
                if (result.error) {
                    alert(result.error.message);
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });
    });
</script>
```

C# mvc5 controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Charge()
        {
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_51H5JwbI0Y3sF_fake_Pb9oadqZNkoZPRJD048gToZsMgDGzCu3D23iEZEnyyCtndB00jrFvKF3W";

            var domain = "http://localhost:55555/settings";

            var metaData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            metaData.Add("DomainID", "here i want to set domain id which will come from html checkout button");


            var options = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateOptions
            {
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
                {
                    "card",
                },
                LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
                {
                  new SessionLineItemOptions
                  {
                    PriceData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
                    {
                      UnitAmount = 900,
                      Currency = "usd",
                      ProductData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
                      {
                        Name = "Premium charge",
                        Description = "this is some description",
                        Metadata = metaData,
                      },
                    },
                    Quantity = 1,
                  },
                },
                Mode = "payment",
                SuccessUrl = domain + "/Domain?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
                CancelUrl = domain + "/Domain",
            };
            var service = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionService();
            Stripe.Checkout.Session session = service.Create(options);
            return Json(new { id = session.Id });

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on where you want the `metadata` to reside / be accessed.

If you want to have the `metadata` end up on the Checkout Session itself ([object ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-metadata)), then you would supply that in the top-level parameters when creating the session ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata)).

If you want the `metadata` to be added to the underlying [Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-metadata) (and Charge), then you should supply it in the nested `payment_intent_data[metadata]` parameter ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata)).